# Why {{ loop.first }} always return when a for is inside another for?

Tags: twig

I need to get first item of a loop in twig. The problem is that the loop is inside another loop.

```
{% for collection in collections %}
    {% for innerItem in collection %}
        {{ loop.first }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This variable always return 1.

Comment: `{{ loop.parent.first }}` is prolly what you wanted

Comment: Mmm no. With {{ loop.first }} i receive the parent. I need the children loop variable.

Comment: Oh.. I misread your question. `loop.first` return `true` when the pointer of the loop is equal to the first element. It does not return an element. You prolly want to write a custom filter for that then

Comment: Please, consider the fact i I have trouble just in the inner for. I have no troubles with "normal" and "single" for.

Comment: Couldn't it just be that the collections you are iterating with the inner loop each contain just one element so that `loop.first` will always be `true`?

Comment: So simple, ... =(. You right!